# HVC and SVC calls in classic autosar

Tags: operating-system, driver, hypervisor, autosar, automotive

I am working on the Classic Autosar platform. In driver there are some HVC/SVC calls which I am expecting to implement for my driver.

Is there any support in Autosar for HVC/SVC calls? What interface we need to call to get HVC/SVC functionality.
(Note: HVC calls are to get the Hypervisor service and SVC calls are to Operating System Service)
I am using Classic Autosar R22-11